# acro: show long acronym name in PDF bookmark

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, acro

I am using the [package acro](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro_en.pdf). I have the following acronym:

```
\DeclareAcronym{SDP}{
  short = SDP,
  long  = Sequential Decision Process,
  long-plural-form = Sequential Decision Processes,
  class = abbrev
}
```

And then I have the section titles:

```
\section{\aclp{SDP}}
\section{\acsp{SDP}}
```

Which correctly prints "Sequential Decision Processes" and "SDPs" in the PDF. However, the PDF bookmarks for the sections both say "SDPs".

In the [documentation](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro_en.pdf), it says you can specify the property `pdfstring` to set what will be printed in the PDF bookmarks. But that gives no options for long and short forms. How can I change the PDF bookmark depending on what the section title is?

Comment: If I can use the long-form code manually where it is needed, either thing works fine. I'll also file a feature request. I can wait a few days for a solution, that is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \acro_expandable_long:n #1
  { \prop_item:Nn \l__acro_long_prop {#1} }

\cs_new:Npn \acro_expandable_long_plural:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:nTF
      { \prop_item:Nn \l__acro_long_plural_form_prop {#1} }
      { \prop_item:Nn \l__acro_long_plural_prop {#1} }
      {
        \prop_item:Nn \l__acro_long_prop {#1}
        \prop_item:Nn \l__acro_long_plural_prop {#1}
      }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \acro_pdf_string_long:n #1
  {
    \acro_if_star_gobble:nTF {#1}
      { \acro_expandable_long:n }
      { \acro_expandable_long:n {#1} }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \acro_pdf_string_long_plural:n #1
  {
    \acro_if_star_gobble:nTF {#1}
      { \acro_expandable_long_plural:n }
      { \acro_expandable_long_plural:n {#1} }
  }

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \acl  \acro_pdf_string_long:n
        \cs_set_eq:NN \aclp \acro_pdf_string_long_plural:n
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareAcronym{SDP}{
  short = SDP,
  long  = Sequential Decision Process,
  long-plural-form = Sequential Decision Processes
}

\DeclareAcronym{CD}{
  short = CD,
  long  = Compact Disc
}

\begin{document}

\section{\acs{CD}, \acs{SDP}}
\section{\acsp{CD}, \acsp{SDP}}
\section{\acl{CD}, \acl{SDP}}
\section{\aclp{CD}, \aclp{SDP}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Until now the decision that `acro` only supports the short form in bookmarks is deliberate – I didn't think long forms were necessary there as bookmarks only serve a limited purpose: linking to the “real” headings where the acronyms are printed as specified. (And at least on my system the bookmarks are truncated most of the time anyway…)

I'll see if I add a more thorough support to the next version.

Comment: "I didn't think long forms where necessary there" Well, it is possible to write out the long version in the section title, there is not that much section title text. Maybe I should have just done that, but I got into the habit of just using \ac.* for everything. This will be very handy, thank you!

Comment: @rhaps0dy Without these modifications the long form still was there in the “real” titles – they were only replaced by the short forms in the bookmarks. And those never get printed.